# Can You please explain to me where's the problem? [SPOj-exercise]

Tags: c++, dynamic-programming

I mean I honestly can't find the issue and this code seems to be very simple to write and I don't get accepted. Maybe You can help me and find the answer as honestly I have no idea. I'm trying to do this exercise on SPOJ: https://www.spoj.com/problems/PIGBANK/. I will be very thankful for any explanation on what is wrong in my approach.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void piggyBank(int, int);
int sumAll(int *,int, int);


/* SUMMARY

    We need to find the smallest value available in the piggy bank

*/

int main()
{
    int t = 0, e = 0, f = 0;
    cin >> t;
    for (int i = 0; i < t; i++)
    {
        cin >> e >> f;
        piggyBank(e, f);
    }
    return 0;
}

void piggyBank(int weightEmpty, int weightFull)
{
    int coinsAmount = 0, *coinValue, *coinWeight, totalWorth = 0, remainingWeight = weightFull - weightEmpty, smallestValPos = 0;
    cin >> coinsAmount;
    coinValue = new int[coinsAmount];
    coinWeight = new int[coinsAmount];
    // getting all the coins and weights in the piggy bank
    for (int i = 0; i < coinsAmount; i++)
    {
        cin >> coinValue[i] >> coinWeight[i];
        if ((remainingWeight / coinWeight[smallestValPos] > remainingWeight / coinWeight[i]) && (remainingWeight % coinWeight[i] == 0)) smallestValPos = i;
    }
    // we need to check how many coinValue[smallestValPos] are there inside piggy bank
    if(remainingWeight%coinWeight[smallestValPos] == 0)totalWorth = remainingWeight / coinWeight[smallestValPos] * coinValue[smallestValPos];
    // output according to the excercise's constraints
    if (totalWorth == 0) cout << "This is impossible.\n";// << endl;
    else cout << "The minimum amount of money in the piggy-bank is " << totalWorth << ".\n"; //<< endl;
}

int sumAll(int *tab,int start, int end)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = start; i < end; i++)
    {
        sum += tab[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Sample Input from SPOJ:

3
10 110
2
1 1
30 50
10 110
2
1 1
50 30
1 6
2
10 3
20 4

Sample output from SPOJ:

The minimum amount of money in the piggy-bank is 60.
The minimum amount of money in the piggy-bank is 100.
This is impossible.

Comment: You can't even state why it's not accepted?

Comment: I get wrong answer as information

Comment: Put it in the question. The site also tags the question as dynamic programming. If I were guessing, you don't do any dynamic programming.

Comment: What's the input, the expected output and the actual output?

Comment: OT: Your code appears to be leaking memory. Maybe switching to std::vector would help.

Comment: yes, it's tagged as dynamic, but I try this simple approach as you can see in my code. Is it necessary to do it with dynamic approach?

Comment: I have a feeling you're not failing on the sample input/output, otherwise you wouldn't have submitted.

Comment: if it was a memory problem i doubt that it they'd tag it as wrong answer

Comment: yes, it's outputting the sample output correctly. At least from what i checked. I was checking if there was any typo or something, but I can't tell.

Comment: From what I know about such sites you're probably exceeding some time limit when they run your code on some large data set.

Comment: In SPOJ, when the user exceeds the time limit they get info: time limit exceeded

Comment: Well looking at your code I doubt the algorithm is correct. Just intuition but it seems to be some kind of greedy algorithm and I don't think such a simple algorithm can solve this problem.

Comment: Yes, pretty much what @stefaanv said.

Comment: Here is an example test case `1 0 7 2 3 3 4 4`. Your algorithm prints `This is impossible.` The correct answer is `The minimum amount of money in the piggy-bank is 7.`

Answer (score 3):

In your solution, you only take in account the least value per weight coin, but if that doesn't add to the exact weight, you also have to use other coins to match the weight. This is when the exercise is becoming interesting.

And of course as mentioned in the comments, why have memory leaks when you can use containers?

Comment: Seems to be the problem. I'll try as you said and check if it goes through. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Given weight W and coins with weight C_i and value V_i, you have the following recurrence relation:

> minValue(W) = min { V_1 + minValue(W-C_1), V_2 + minValue(W-C_2), ... }
>   minValue(0) = 0

You need to account for some weights not being reachable (ie W=3 when you only have coins with weight 5 and 10), but otherwise it is pretty straightforward.

The recurrence relation above lends itself very well to dynamic programming: simply start computing from W=0 until you get to the target weight.